# max-height in safari not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap.min.css, i have this tag which cannot be changed:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Now, I have to display an image in safari and is creating an issue. No issue in other browsers. Here's my HTML which cannot be changed either:

```
<div class="safari">
    <img src="images/image.jpg">
</div>
```

And this is the custom.css which i added:

```
.safari img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The output is that the height of the image is like a thumbnail and not displaying the entire image. The problem is because of the max-height and max-width in the bootstrap.css

I can only edit the custom.css and i'm at wits end to figure out how to overwrite the above two max-height and max-width at custom.css

Comment: use `height: auto !important;` just to see if that would solve it. Not saying to use `!important`, but just to check. If that does not work you have CSS some other place that is causing your issue.

Comment: Reset the values to their defaults: `max-height: none; max-width: none;`